# Google App Script to perform a CTRL A + CTRL C + CTRL V from different webpages

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

I have to send my boss a report everyday. Basically I have 6 sheets on one google sheets file. Everyday I need to go to our internal website and do the following steps:

- Go to URL 1, do CTRL A + CTRL C and then simply paste it (CTRL V) in A:1 of Sheet1.
- Go to URL 2, do CTRL A + CTRL C and then simply paste it (CTRL V) in A:1 of Sheet2.
- Go to URL 2, do CTRL A + CTRL C and then simply paste it (CTRL V) in A:1 of Sheet3.
- And so on ten times...

I am trying to automate this but literally don't know how. I am newbie and tried looking into some tutorials but the code always copy the HTML code and not just the "visual" content of the website. I just need a CTRL A + CTRL C from different webpages and paste it on different sheets.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider looking at Lua language to automate some basic keystrokes. There's probably more efficient ways to capture a site's contents using google scripts, but if copy paste works, then great. Also if you're Sonoma, don't tell your boss.

Comment: You *could* try write a function using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) and read the html content, then, extract the data you need for insert them on your sheet(s).

Comment: UrlFetchApp might work for scraping some web pages but not all. It looks that you will need a different tool. By the way,  asking for software recommendations is off-topic here, try [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Basically it must be done using Google App Scripts bc its the only program we got access to at work. I will look into UrlFetchApp.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to automate this would be making a macro.

If you wanted to automate it with a script I don't know how you would do this exactly but, I can give you pointers on what you might need to do.

For getting data you would need to make a get request to the site, then parse the html or scrape the html to get the text you are looking for.

For setting spreadsheat values you have to go through the Google api and set it through that.

Comment: Only within the google sheet though. This question requires going to different pages.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this will help me out for the second part but I think I need a javascript code to get that copy paste from different pages, like pgSystemTester mentioned

Comment: Google App scripts doesn't have a global method to copy paste (which is probably good so it can't control your computer). If you have to use google app scripts you can capture the websites contents as an HTML reference, but it's not the same as your copy/paste routine.